# How to open new tab group in ionic framework (Vue.js) after the user logs into the application

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

At first, I want to display the login and register tab pages but after the user logs in or register I want to show a new group tab.

I tried some solutions but it didn+t work for me

Comment: what do you mean by "show a new group tab"? and what did you try? what errors did you run into?  post some code that helps explains exactly what you're trying to do. asking for technical solutions requires technical, detailed explanations of the problem.

Comment: Use a variable and save the value there....